# "Insert Into Select" writing to table but contains sub-query reading from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am adding records into my table "SampleTestLimits" using an "Insert Into Select", but which also has a sub-query reading from the same table to perform a count for me.

I don't think the sub-query is seeing the earlier records added by my "Insert Into Select". It's the same for Oracle and SQL Server. The code for SQL Server is shown below (my sub-query begins with "SELECT COALESCE...").

I have another stored procedure which does work in a similar situation.

Would appreciate it if anybody could tell if what I'm doing is a no no.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateSampleTestLimits]
@SampleCode as NVARCHAR(80),
@TestPosition as smallint,
@TestCode NVARCHAR(20),
@TestVersion smallint,
@EnterDate as integer,
@EnterTime as smallint,
@EnterUser as NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SampleTestLimits
([AuditNumber]
,[LimitNumber]
,[ComponentRow]
,[ComponentColumn]
,[ComponentName]
,[TestPosition]
,[SampleCode]
,[AuditFlag]
,[LimitSource]
,[LimitType]
,[UpperLimitEntered]
,[UpperLimitValue]
,[LowerLimitEntered]
,[LowerLimitValue]
,[LimitTextColour]
,[LimitPattern]
,[LimitForeColour]
,[LimitBackColour]
,[CreatedDate]
,[CreatedTime]
,[CreatedUser]
,[LimitText]
,[FilterName]
,[deleted]
,IsRuleBased)
SELECT 1 --starting auditnumber
,(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(LimitNumber), 0) + 1 AS NextLimitNumber FROM SampleTestLimits WHERE SampleCode=@SampleCode AND TestPosition=@TestPosition AND ComponentRow=1 AND ComponentColumn=1 AND AuditFlag=0) -- TFS bug# 3952: Calculate next limit number.
,ComponentRow
,ComponentColumn
,(select ComponentName from TestComponents TC where TC.TestCode=@TestCode and TC.ComponentColumn=TestLimits.ComponentColumn and TC.ComponentRow = TestLimits.ComponentRow and TC.AuditNumber=TestLimits.AuditNumber)
,@TestPosition
,@SampleCode
,0 --auditflag
,1 --limitsource = test
,[LimitType]
,[UpperLimitEntered]
,[UpperLimitValue]
,[LowerLimitEntered]
,[LowerLimitValue]
,[LimitTextColour]
,[LimitPattern]
,[LimitForeColour]
,[LimitBackColour]
,@EnterDate
,@EnterTime
,@EnterUser
,[LimitText]
,[FilterName]
,0 --deleted
,0 --rule based
FROM TestLimits join Tests on Tests.TestCode=TestLimits.TestCode and Tests.AuditNumber= TestLimits.AuditNumber  WHERE Tests.TestCode=@TestCode and Tests.auditnumber=@TestVersion and ([TestLimits].FilterString is null or DATALENGTH([TestLimits].FilterString)=0)
END
```

Comment: It won't see it. See execution plan and check for `Table spool`. Optimizer use them to avoid nasty effects like infinite loops so the table/index is first spooled. Please share execution plan. Search for [this](http://aboutsqlserver.com/blog/2014/2014-01-07/pic01.png)

Comment: Could you delete 'AS NextLimitNumber' and then run it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Removing "AS.NextLimitNumber" doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got an image of the execution plan but I don't think I have the technology to get it into this post, and my XML version is too long to go in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your logic correctly (ie. that you want the nextlimitnumber to increase by 1 for each row being added), in Oracle, I'd do it by using the analytic function row_number() to work out what number to add to the previous max value, something like:

```
INSERT INTO sampletestlimits (auditnumber,
                              limitnumber,
                              componentrow,
                              componentcolumn,
                              componentname,
                              testposition,
                              samplecode,
                              auditflag,
                              limitsource,
                              limittype,
                              upperlimitentered,
                              upperlimitvalue,
                              lowerlimitentered,
                              lowerlimitvalue,
                              limittextcolour,
                              limitpattern,
                              limitforecolour,
                              limitbackcolour,
                              createddate,
                              createdtime,
                              createduser,
                              limittext,
                              filtername,
                              deleted,
                              isrulebased)
  SELECT 1, --starting auditnumber
         (SELECT COALESCE (MAX (limitnumber), 0) + 1 AS nextlimitnumber
          FROM   sampletestlimits
          WHERE      samplecode = p_samplecode
                 AND testposition = p_testposition
                 AND componentrow = 1
                 AND componentcolumn = 1
                 AND auditflag = 0)
           + row_number() over (partition by testposition, componentrow, componentcolumn, auditflag) as nextlimitnumber, -- TFS bug# 3952: Calculate next limit number.
         componentrow,
         componentcolumn,
         (SELECT componentname
          FROM   testcomponents tc
          WHERE      tc.testcode = p_testcode
                 AND tc.componentcolumn = testlimits.componentcolumn
                 AND tc.componentrow = testlimits.componentrow
                 AND tc.auditnumber = testlimits.auditnumber),
         p_testposition,
         p_samplecode,
         0, --auditflag
         1, --limitsource = test
         limittype,
         upperlimitentered,
         upperlimitvalue,
         lowerlimitentered,
         lowerlimitvalue,
         limittextcolour,
         limitpattern,
         limitforecolour,
         limitbackcolour,
         p_enterdate,
         p_entertime,
         p_enteruser,
         limittext,
         filtername,
         0, --deleted
         0  --rule based
  FROM   testlimits
         JOIN tests
           ON     tests.testcode = testlimits.testcode
              AND tests.auditnumber = testlimits.auditnumber
  WHERE      tests.testcode = p_testcode
         AND tests.auditnumber = p_testversion
         AND (   testlimits.filterstring IS NULL
              OR datalength (testlimits.filterstring) = 0);
```

I had to guess at what the partition by clause would need to contain - adjust that as necessary for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the problem with row_number is that it doesn't consider records that might already be in the database to start with; it just considers what's been returned by the Insert Into Select.

Comment: I presumed that was what the `select max()` subquery was about?

Comment: Here's an example that hopefully demonstrates what I was trying to get at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18ac6/1

Comment: Sorry for being a bit slow, I think understand what you're doing in the code example above now: you're using my COALESCE MAX to get the initial number of rows and then adding the row_number to get the next highest number. I can see that would work! My only worry is that, in some circumstances my COALESCE MAX does seem to find the rows being added by the INSERT INTO SELECT, how could I guard against that do you think?

Comment: insert the rows and then update the nextlimitnumber column afterwards?